# Hadnling redirect with ajax, Restlet server

Tags: jquery, authentication, restlet

I'm trying to log-in to my Restlet server (I'm using the latest version of restlet).
On my server I have a cookie authenticator guarding the resources.
I'm using the following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: http://localhost/login?targetUri=/html/business.html#5,
data: $('#login').serialize(),
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
if (data.redirect) {
window.location.href = data.redirect;
}
}
});
```

As also mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Because the answer is HTTP redirect the browser automatically sends a GET request for the redirected address and then data.redirect is undefined. 'data' actually contains the content of the redirected page.
I changed it to:

```
if (textStatus == "success") { 
document.location = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Location");
...
```

But this end up with two GET requests to `/html/business.html`.
What is the right way to handle the redirect?